# Trying do display categories of blogs and total number done by each user. -wordpress

Tags: settings, blogs

Trying do display categories of blogs and total number done by each user.
The total number show display on user profile.
I have done this but is shows sum total.

```
<div class="author_content1">
   <p>
      <?php the_author(); ?>
      has blogged
      <?php the_author_posts(); ?>
      posts
   </p>
</div>
```

Need to achieve this :

[image]